# Wait for values in the database to update and then return value

Tags: c#

I need to get a value from the database SQL Server and then use it in my code, I do it this way:

```
var batchNumber = RepositoryIp.GetIpInfo(id, "CHARG").FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is that I cannot continue the flow of my code while the `GetIpInfo` method is returning null. How could I do this correctly?

Comment: are you using sql server or another rmdbs?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. The ```GetIpInfo``` queries the db with EF 6

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/detect-changes-sqldependency?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: When do you expect it to return a value eventually? Within (milli)seconds, or can it take hours?

Comment: in a few minutes